# Angular JS, I get how it works, but where should I use it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I just skimmed the Angular JS documentation, and it's rather interesting I have to say, but maybe because I have a lack of immagination (perhaps even of intelligence), I cannot figure out many practical uses for that.

In which situation would you say: "Oh, thank God there's Angular JS and I can do this task with that."?

Comment: questions asking for opinions often get closed, but you can use angularjs for a whole host of things, here [are some examples](https://builtwith.angularjs.org/)

Comment: I'm not actually asking for opinions. I'm asking for practical uses of Angular JS. Thanks!

Comment: https://vimeo.com/68215604

A great little tutorial that gets you started. Its a nice framework for building single page applications...

Comment: If you want to buid a web application (not a website) good example is ***plunker***.  In general all SPA sites should work with Angular. also there's a good REST integration with Angular

Comment: [joke] wow, i just saw the cars... interesting i have to say , but I would not know what to do with that, I do it all  with my wagon and my horses [/joke]